# Do not mutate Vuex store state outside mutation handlers (ERROR)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

So I'm getting the following error message:

**[Vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.**

The reason behind this error according to the Vuex [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html) is because the following code tries to directly mutate the state.

```
<template>
   <div v-for="item in basicInformation" :key="item.id">
     <el-col :span="12">
          <el-form-item label="First Name">
              <el-input v-model="item.firstName" />
          </el-form-item>
     </el-col>
   </div>
</template>

export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapState(['teststore']),
            basicInformation: {
                get() {
                    return this.teststore.personData.basicInformation
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit('updateBasic', value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get why Vuex is throwing that error, since I am still trying to directly mutate the state. So a solution for this particular problem according to the docs would be using a two-way computed property with a setter (like in the example above), and that works fine for a single inputfield. However, I have A LOT of inputfields for the user to fill in. Consider the following code:

```
personData: {
        basicInformation: [
            {
                firstName: '',
                surname: '',
                email: '',
                phone: '',
                street: '',
                city: '',
                position: '',
                website: '',
            }
        ],
}
```

Creating a two-way computed property with a setter for all my inputfields seems very verbose. Is there an easy way where I can use Vuex and preferably `v-model` with an array of objects to create inputfields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-ibjbr

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(value, key) in basicInformation" :key="key">
      <el-col :span="12">
        <el-form-item :label="keyToLabel(key)">
          <el-input :value="value" @input="onInput({ key, value: $event })" />
        </el-form-item>
      </el-col>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['teststore']),
    basicInformation() {
      return this.teststore.personData.basicInformation
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onInput({ key, value }) {
      this.$store.commit('updateBasic', { key, value })
    },
    keyToLabel(key) {
      // This is only an example
      const keyToLabel = {
        firstName: 'First Name',
        // And so on...
      }
      return keyToLabel[key]
    },
  },
}

// And in your store, something like this
const store = {
  // ...
  mutations: {
    updateBasic(state, { key, value }) {
      state.teststore.basicInformation[key] = value
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply! I tried implementing this but got the following error message: ```Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String, Number, got Object``` I created a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-7bb3c) with your code. Could you maybe point out to me where this error comes from?

Comment: Sure, the problem is that basicInformation is an array (which I don't understand why). I removed it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-ibjbr. Don't hesitate to add `console.log` statements to try to see what's going on. Also, if you did need the array (for example to show the basic information of many people), you would need a wrapping element (ex: a `<div>`) with a v-for.

Comment: Hi Phil, again thank you very much for helping me out.. I know I'm probably asking obvious questions, I'm just trying to wrap my head around all this... The reason it has to be an array is because the user is able to do [this](https://gyazo.com/73062dc49c97dd9225d091f322c081a6) with a different array of objects in the main personData obj. I again tried implementing your solution with an outer div to get it to work with an array, but again I cant't get it to work... See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-7bb3c) . Could you please help me out one more time :-S ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **copy** of `basicInformation` to have this inside component scope.

So associate a computed property to `basicInformation` and use it in v-models should kill this warning.

```html
<template>
   <div v-for="item in localBasicInformation" :key="item.id">
     <el-col :span="12">
          <el-form-item label="First Name">
              <el-input v-model="item.firstName" />
          </el-form-item>
     </el-col>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
computed: {
  localBasicInformation() {
    return [...this.basicInformation];
  },
},
</script>
```

Just pay attemption about the differences between shallow and deep copy. If `this.localBasicInformation` **is deep, spread operator will not work** and you will need something like [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) from lodash.