# Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers error for set state array

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, dynamicform

After writing the data to vuex state I am getting error because I am using v-model. The instance has both object and array instances. There is no error in the object state but I am getting the following error in the array part. Has anyone encountered this situation? what could be the solution

Steps:

1. Write data to the form(firstName).
2. Click the Set State Array button
3. Change the data in the form(firstName).

**Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.**

```js
export const state = () => ({
  formsArray: [],
  formObject: {}
});

const mutations = {
  SET_FORMSARRAY(state, payload) {
    console.log('formsArray', payload);
    state.formsArray = [...payload];
  },
  SET_FORMSOBJECT(state, payload) {
    console.log('formObject', payload);
    state.formObject = { ...payload };
  }
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <p>  {{forms}} </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div
      v-for="(form, index) in forms"
      :key="index"
      flat
      outlined
      rounded="lg"
    >
      <span>{{index+1}}. firstName</span>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="form.firstName"
        solo
      />
    </div>
    <v-btn
      elevation="2"
      class="ma-2"
      @click="setStateArray"
    >SET STATE ARRAY</v-btn>
    <br>
    <div style="margin-top:20px">
         <span>firstName</span>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="formsObject.firstName"
        solo
      />
     <span>lastName</span>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="formsObject.lastName"
        solo
      />
    <v-btn
      elevation="2"
        class="ma-2"
      @click="setStateObject"
    >SET STATE OBJECT</v-btn>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
      <p>State Array:  {{formsArray}} </p>
    <br>
    <br>
      <p> State Object:  {{formObject}} </p>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations,mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    data() {
    return {
      forms: [],
      formsObject: {
        firstName: 'sad',
        lastName: 'sd'
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      const formData = {
        firstName: '',
      }
      this.forms.push(formData)
    }
  },
    computed: {
    ...mapState('form', ['formsArray','formObject']),
  },
  methods:{
    ...mapMutations('form',['SET_FORMSARRAY','SET_FORMSOBJECT']),
    setStateArray(){
       this.SET_FORMSARRAY(this.forms)
    },
    setStateObject(){
       this.SET_FORMSOBJECT(this.formsObject)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

Example :https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuex-set-state-array-error

Comment: it inherits the binding, copy the object your passing in, I generally make a global util which is somewhat like a `$copy = v => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v))`, then use it throughout like `this.$copy(obj)` when passing things back to the store. Really you need to add your code here, else once you have removed the workspace, your link has rotted and your question is then lacking a verifiable example, be aware the title of your question will show up in any search engine search as this is a common gotcha

Comment: The error means what it says. The solution is to mutate the store only with actions/mutations. You shallowly copy the array so it becomes a part of the store, then you continue to mutate it.

Comment: Please make a search for this one. It was asked a lot of times already, with those exact keywords.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not mutate Vuex store state outside mutation handlers (ERROR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699759/do-not-mutate-vuex-store-state-outside-mutation-handlers-error)

Comment: @kissu Unfortunately this is not the answer to my question. The solution must be in the right approach. I request you to answer after trying on stackblitz example. Of course, we do research before asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the test cases is that the array is actually an array of objects, while the object case is a flat object. When you're writing to the store with the spread syntax, this works fine for the object. When trying this with the array, only the array itself is being copied, but the reference to the objects inside still persists - therefor the error is being thrown. A possible solution would be to also use the spread syntax for the objects inside the array, or to use a deep-copy approach for writing into the store.

Comment: Thanks, deep copy was the solution for me

Comment: @EnesGenc You're welcome! If you like, you can mark my answer as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Glad that the correct answer was indeed a deep copy! @EnesGenc (this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57699922/8816585)

Comment: @kissu code that works :)

`const temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload))`

Comment: @EnesGenc you have some quirks with this solution tho: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-clone-javascript-object/